# Elasticsearch - Bool query failed to parse search

Tags: elasticsearch

So I am attempting to use a bool query that checks a user's id against other user's blacklist, as well as removing users that a user has blacklisted in the results.

Each query works fine on its own, but not together. I was under the impression from the elasticsearch documentation that inside a bool query I could chain them with commas.

If someone could tell me where I'm going wrong, it'd be much appreciated.

```
client.search({
  index: 'firebase',
  type: 'user',
  size: 500,
  body: {
    "query": {
       "filtered" : {
           "query" : {
               "bool" : {
                   "must_not" : {
                     "terms": { "id": user.blacklist},
                     "term": { "blacklist": user.id}
                   }
               }
             },
             "filter": {
                "and": query
             }

       }
 }

}
}).then(function (resp) {
    var hits = resp.hits.hits;
    res.send(hits);

    console.log(hits);
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.sendStatus(500);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.  Your `must_not` query should be an array of objects, instead of just an object:

```
"bool" : {
  "must_not" : [
    {"terms": { "id": user.blacklist}},
    {"term": { "blacklist": user.id}}
  ]
}
```

Don't forget the extra brackets around each of the term(s) searches.

In [the ElasticSearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), notice how the `should` clause in the example query is an array instead of an object since it has more than one sub-clause.

Comment: Thanks man...one question though. user.blacklist is an array of id's, shouldn't that be a terms search in order to iterate through it to match against id?

Comment: You are right, terms in the way to go if you want to match multiple values.

Comment: Oops, you're right.  I should have picked up on the fact that blacklist was an array and not a single value.  I'll edit my answer.